# I have a problem when I convert python file to exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe, converters

when I click on the program to run it I see the message say : Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "employee manager.py", line 388, in <module>
  File "tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 128, in __init__
  File "tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 258, in __init__
  File "babel\dates.py", line 351, in get_day_names
  File "babel\core.py", line 652, in days
  File "babel\core.py", line 363, in _data
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 140, in load
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 146, in load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'
```

I need to open the program

Comment: Did you install babel?

Answer (score 2):

A: More information is most likely needed to solve this

Also, it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'
"numbers" is a subscription of babel. If you want to grab a numbers subscription, try doing: `from babel import numbers`.

Good Luck! I will try to correspond as needed!

Comment: Assuming they did pip install babel

Comment: true, though "babel.numbers" isn't proper syntax for a module anyhow.

Comment: @Jonathan what? wdym not proper syntax? how is it not proper? one can surely do `import babel.numbers`

Comment: hmmm... I haven't worked with babel personally, but generally, the "." modifier is reserved for functions, such as;

`class Animal(): def bark(): print(sound)

x = Animal()
x.bark()`

Comment: In terms of a module, you use: from babel import {sub-module name}

Comment: @Jonathan well, no, you can also do `import babel.submodule` and then use as `bable.submodule.variable` and similar, if `babel` is a package

Comment: How can a submodule have explicit variables? Aren't modules just classes and methods imported and available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using PyInstaller, and that you're having a problem launching the exe because of an issue with tkcalendar. There is an [issue on tkcalendar's github page about this](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/32), and a [comment](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/32#issuecomment-431131534) that solves this problem:

`pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import babel.numbers script.py`

I was having the same problem and this worked for me.